# I set my bitlocker preboot pin in Arabic

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker, tpm, pin

I was trying to set a preboot pin for bitlocker for my laptop. I enabled extended and set the pin in Arabic (thought it wid be more secure). Now at the pin entry page, the keyboard layout is in en-us. and theres no option to change the layout. Any and all help is desperately needed and appreciated.
p.s. I cant find my recovery key file so that routes gone.

Comment: Without the recovery key your out of luck. There is nothing you can do.

Comment: i remember the preboot pin. i just have to change the keyboard layout to arabic for it to work. is there no way to do that?

Comment: The solution is to disable bitlocker within pre-boot

Comment: If you have another HDD you could in theory, install Windows 10 on that, attach your current HDD by USB install the Arabic language pack and disable bitlocker that way also.  Confused how you switched to the Arabic layout originally though.

Comment: Tried that. Instead of asking for the pin, it still asks for the recovery key. And i set it in arabic by enabling enhanced pin in gp policy. After that it allows you to set it in any way.

Comment: Without being able to add the keyboard layout you need your out of luck

Comment: @Bachsau - I will go away now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have on your laptop, or can plug in, an extended keyboard and you can remember what the actual characters were, then you might be able to enter the Unicode values of the characters (much like when you type an accent for another language). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode).

Otherwise, you don't have much hope. You will have to reinstall windows using a UEFI Recovery tool (If you laptop has one) or using a USB disk. There is little hope of recovering data using a live disk or similar because the partition is encrypted with BitLocker.

Comment: How do i get windows to accept the unicode values. I remember the characters but if the unicode for a character is U-0685, then do i write it without the u- like 0685. but if i do write it like that, windows will view it as the pin and get the unicode for those. Forgive me, but I havent had much experience with unicode

Comment: @AhmedAbuBakrAziz Typing the Unicode value is done as mentioned by cybernard in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this really old trick. Turn your NUM lock on. Hold down the ALT key and type the number, but only on the numeric keypad. Release the ALT key and a symbol should appear. Practice in the username field.

For some reason ALT 685 and ALT 0685 are different try both.
Also if you don't get symbols, try both ALT keys, on most systems either ALT will work, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

After enabling Bitlocker, I too set a Boot Password containing a foreign symbol - without realising this exact problem, same as you. I chose the 'Print recovery key' option, and saved it as a PDF on the Desktop.

After much Googling, and finding out that you can't change the keyboard layout during Boot, and that <kbd>Alt</kbd> codes don't work either; I was just about to reinstall Windows... but I thought, what the hell, I'll try the `ESC for Recovery` option. It brings you back to the Windows login screen, and after logging in - it tells you that BitLocker failed to enable. Crisis avoided!

This time I've set an 'American' password `;)`