# BitLocker PIN not working since it includes a £

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I have set a BitLocker PIN and now I'm locked out since I cannot type the correct PIN. The reason I can think of is my PIN contains a "£" symbol since I have a UK keyboard layout. However, when typing the BitLocker PIN it is US layout and the £ symbol does not exist. How can I get around this problem? How can I type the £ symbol in the BitLocker blue screen?

I have tried ASCII Codes (ALT + 156 and ALT + 0163) but did not print the £ symbol.

Comment: Are you seeing this PIN prompt when you first time the computer on?

Comment: Yes, I am seeing the prompt. I am typing Insert to see it.

Comment: If all else fails, could you do a bitlocker recovery?

Comment: Similar question: https://superuser.com/questions/1164543/i-set-my-bitlocker-preboot-pin-in-arabic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type pound sign(£) using US keyboard, in Windows, Linux and Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/293119/how-to-type-pound-sign%c2%a3-using-us-keyboard-in-windows-linux-and-mac) Also see https://superuser.com/questions/955783/setting-the-default-input-method-for-the-windows-10-login-screen

Answer (score 1):

1. **Make a disk image** in case an attempt to fix the issue **permanently** locks BitLocker. This can be done using tools such as [Macrium Rescue Environment](https://blog.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61) or [alternative](https://www.g2.com/products/macrium-reflect/competitors/alternatives).
2. Try using the [on-screen keyboard](https://www.alphr.com/windows-log-in-without-keyboard/).
3. Try an external keyboard that has the **£** symbol.
4. You can use "data recovery agents":   the drive must be mounted as a data drive on another computer for the data recovery agent to unlock it. This might require Support help.

Comment: Changing the keyboard will not help. The asker uses an enhanced PIN and for those, Microsoft warns that only characters that exist on an EN-US keyboard can be used. Solution: unlock it with the numerical recovery password and change the PIN to something numerical or to something that exists on the en-us layout as well.

Comment: It was fixed by a recovery-key and changing the PIN